# Working with an unsaved excel workbook in python

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

I am exporting excel documents out of another program and need to rename them under a different name, I have gotten to the point where I can pull the open excel workbook into my code, as you can see below, but I can't figure out how to rename the workbook to `foo.xlxs` going this route. What is my most optimal way to attack this?

```py
from win32com.client import Dispatch
xlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Visible=1

name = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Name

print(name)
```

Output:

```
activeworkbook.xlsx
```

Comment: Try `xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs("foo.xlsx")`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas

Answer (score 0):

This is possible solution.

```
import win32com.client

excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add()

#what you do to your workbook, add value to sheets

workbook.SaveAs(workbook_full_dir)
workbook.Close(True)
```